# Solaris: Spooling filesystem is full

Tags: command-line, filesystems, solaris, printing, lp

I have a Solaris 5.8 machine that will no longer print. print job that come from the terminal say: "See if spooling file system is full"

I had a look around /var/spool but it isn’t particularly populated. I tried deleting the temp files, but the message remains, after reboot. The last time I saw this was in 2011, and I can't recall how to fix it, but I need to be able to print again.

Comment: do you see any of the filesystems, especially `/var`, at 100% capacity, when you run `df` command ?

Comment: "See if spooling file system is full" is not a message Solaris 8 used to generate. Please make sure you post the actual message displayed. Also, "not particularly populated" means nothing to the rest of us. Please tell how much space is used in /var/spool, and even more, how much space is available there: `df -k /var/spool` (as MelBurslan already asked). System messages might also be useful (`dmesg`).

Answer (score 1):

I did `df -a` and saw root was 100% in use. 
so then I tried: `du -ak / | sort -nr | less`
to get the directories holding the most space.
while that was attempting to run, it crashed, saying "/var/tmp
is full"

so I went into /var/tmp, and deleted everything. 
once I did that, I was able to print again.

for giggles, I ran  `du -ak / | sort -nr | less`
again, to try and find some of the larger folders. But many of the things that turned up from that are required, and cannot be deleted safely.

previously I had tried clearing out the spool, but there was nothing in it.
after clearing out /var/tmp `df -a` shows disk use around 80% of 1.5GB.

Thanks for the consideration guys!

Comment: So it would seem you resolved your issue.  Usually /var is configured as it's own FS, but since you note root at 100%, I'm wondering if /var is on /.